# List View Widget not updating on lock screen

Tags: android, widget, lockscreen

```
package com.Widget;

import java.util.Random;
import com.Launcher.LauncherActivity;
import com.Widget.wifiwidget.R;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

/**
 * A very basic {@link AppWidgetProvider} implementation that delegates the
 * actual processing to the {@link WidgetService}.
 */

public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_EXPEND = "ActionReceiverExpend";
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_EMERGENCY = "ActionReceiverEmergency";
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_DIAL = "ActionReceiverDial";
    public static String EXTRA_WORD = "com.Widget.WORD";

    int id;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context ctxt, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        /*
         * AppWidgetProvider extends BroadcastReceiver, so we must not spend
         * lots of processing time in this class. Actual processing is done in a
         * Service so that this method can return as quickly as possible.
         */
        Log.d("onUpdate", "onUpdate");
        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {

            id = new Random().nextInt(10000000);

            Intent svcIntent = new Intent(ctxt, ListItemsService.class);
            svcIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_EXPEND);
            svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    appWidgetIds[i] + id);
            svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(svcIntent
                    .toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

            RemoteViews widget = new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget);

            widget.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIds[i] + id, R.id.userData,
                    svcIntent);

            Intent clickIntent = new Intent(ctxt, LauncherActivity.class);
            PendingIntent clickPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 0,
                    clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            widget.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.userData, clickPI);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], widget);
        }

        ctxt.startService(openIntentForlistService(ctxt));
        ctxt.startService(getIntentForService(ctxt));

        super.onUpdate(ctxt, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        Log.d("onReceive", "onReceive");
        context.startService(openIntentForlistService(context));
    }

    /**
     * Stops the background service when the widget is removed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Log.d("onDeleted", "onDeleted");
        context.stopService(getIntentForService(context));
        context.stopService(openIntentForlistService(context));

        super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to create the correct {@link Intent} to use when working
     * with the {@link WidgetService}.
     * 
     * @param context
     *            Context to use for the Intent
     * @return Intent that can be used to interact with the
     *         {@link WidgetService}
     */
    private Intent getIntentForService(Context context) {
        Intent widgetService = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
                WidgetService.class);
        return widgetService;
    }

    private Intent openIntentForlistService(Context context) {
        Intent dataListService = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
                ListItemsService.class);
        return dataListService;
    }

}
```

> 

```
public class ListItemsService extends RemoteViewsService {

    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Start ListItemsService", "Start ListItemsService");
        return (new WordListViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), intent));
    }
}
}
```

> My listView of widget is not updating on lock screen, it seems like **RemoteViewsService** is not calling from lock screen.

Please see my code of WidgetProvider Class

I think this is enough code to explain the issue

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem and got solution.
In the onReceive() method of your WidgetProvider class just put the following code to update the widget on lock screen:

```
try {
        // Code for update on lock screen
        int ids[] = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(
                new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class));
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
                .getInstance(context);
        onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, ids);
        appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(ids,
                R.layout.widget);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i was facing the same problem and want to update my widget on Lock Screen like Gmail do. Above code is working like charm.

Comment: i really appreciate your help it is working fine now.